# Помогите с ошибкой. TypeError: Safe2.unlock() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, ооп, наследование, type-error

Вот код

```py
class Safe:
    password = "592375x&20"


class Safe2(Safe):
    data = "Пароль ромашка"
    def unlock(self):
        a = input("Введите парол: ")
        if( a == self.password):
            return self.data
        else:
            return "ошибка"


s1 = Safe2()
s1.unlock()
s = Safe()

print("Секретна інформація ",s1.unlock("592375x&20"))
```

Вот что выводит:

```
TypeError: Safe2.unlock() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Answer (score 1):

`input` работает не так, как вы ожидаете, он никак не связан с передачей аргументов в метод. Чтобы можно было передать в методе `unlock` аргумент, вам нужно описать его в определении этого метода:

```
class Safe:
     password = "592375x&20"

class Safe2(Safe):
    data = "Пароль ромашка"

    def unlock(self, a):        # <--- Вот так вот
        if a == self.password:
            return self.data
        else:
            return "ошибка"

s1 = Safe2()
print("Секретна інформація ",s1.unlock("592375x&20"))
```